# Import globally used library module into angular project modules

Tags: angular, software-design, angular-fontawesome

I think I did something wrong here.

I want to use `angular-fontawesome` [module](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome). Following the instructions to import it into `AppModule` successfully.

```
export class AppModule {
constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) {
    // Add an icon to the library for convenient access in other components
    library.addIcons(
        faUsers,
        faUserCircle,
        faDesktop,
        faTachometerAlt,
        faWrench,
        faFolder,
        faChartArea,
        faTable,
        faSearch,
        faBell,
        faFileAlt,
        faExclamationTriangle,
        faDonate,
        faEnvelope,
        faUser,
        faCogs,
        faList,
        faSignOutAlt,
        faAngleUp,
        faLaughWink,
        faServer,
        faWarehouse,
        faPlusCircle
    )
}
```

But when I want to  use it in my own in-project module, say `admin.module.ts`. I have to import all  that again? The same code have to be placed into `admin.module.ts` again?

It seems to me. `AppModule` is the root module. I get that if I have other modules that I want to use icons then I might have to do this. But, really? Even the `AppModule` is not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FaIconLibrary` is an [application-level singleton](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/src/lib/icon-library.ts#L10), so you only need to add icons to the library once. However you should add `FontAwesomeModule` to `imports` of your `AdminModule` to make `<fa-icon>` component accessible to the components declared in the `AdminModule` (it's a standard [Angular thing](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules#angular-modularity)).

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63251497/1377864) interesting to read.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation

Icons can be registered once in app.module with FaIconLibrary.addIcons() or FaIconLibrary.addIconPacks(). Icons added to the library will be available to any other components whose parent module also imports FontAwesomeModule.

So re check next steps

```
1   Import { FontAwesomeModule, FaIconLibrary } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome'
2   Add FontAwesomeModule to imports
3   Inject FaIconLibrary into constructor of the module.
4   Import an icon like { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
5   Add icon to the library with library.addIcons(faCoffee)
```